# Returning Observable is not working

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am just playing with RxSwift to better understand the concepts. I am trying to validate email. However, the subscriber doesn't call when I return an Observable back. I thought this might work. Any suggestions?

```
var emailAddressValid: Observable<String>{
        return self.userEmailAddress.asObservable().filter({ (userEmail) -> Bool in
            userEmail.count > 0
        }).flatMap({ (userEmail) -> Observable<String> in
            if userEmail == "abcd@gmail.com"{
                //This works perfectly
                return .just("007")
            } else {
                let emailDomain = userEmail.components(separatedBy: "@").last
                if emailDomain != nil {
                    //nothing happens in onNext
                    //This returns back an Observable<String>
                    return DataService.instance.checkDomainIsRegistered(domainName: emailDomain!)
                } else {
                    return .just("0")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Although the app works. However, there isn't any compiler error as well. But the onNext in the Observer doesn't work when I return DataService.instance.checkDomainIsRegistered(domainName: emailDomain!)

```
func checkDomainIsRegistered(domainName: String) -> Observable<String>{
        print(domainName)
        return Observable<String>.create{ data in
            self._REF_DOMAIN_NAMES.queryOrdered(byChild: "domainName").queryEqual(toValue: domainName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (domainNameSnapshot) in
                if(domainNameSnapshot.exists()){
                    print("1")
                    data.onNext("1")
                } else {
                    print("0")
                    data.onNext("0")
                }
            }, withCancel: { (error) in
                data.onError(error)
            })
            data.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the call to

```
self._REF_DOMAIN_NAMES.queryOrdered(byChild: "domainName")
    .queryEqual(toValue: domainName)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (domainNameSnapshot) in })
```

is likely being dispatched to a background thread or queue.

In the meantime, your Observable `checkDomainIsRegistered` then completes with `data.onCompleted()` while probably running on the main thread.

The results is that `onNext()` is never being allowed to be called. You can verify this is happening by temporarily removing the `onCompleted()`.

Answer (score 0):

And if called `data.onError(error)`, event stream may be broken. You should catch that.